# POST Request to Clockify via Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, clockify

I am attempting to use the Clockify API (documentation here: https://clockify.me/developers-api#tag-Client) to add clients based on the name of a given spreadsheet in Google Sheets. My code is as follows:

```
function ClockifyManAdd() {
var filedata = {
  'name' : ss.getSheetName()
  };
var headers = {"X-Api-Key" : "[MYAPIKEY]", "content-type" : "application/json"};
var payload = {'name' : JSON.stringify(filedata)};
var clockifyoptions = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'headers' : headers,
  'payload' : payload
  };
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/[MYWORKSPACEID]/clients/', clockifyoptions);
}
```

This code returns an Error 400 - Bad Request (particularly around the "name" token; the error claims that it was expecting "True, False, or Null"). Can anyone point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue/Solution:

- ***Nested payload object:*** Your payload has `{name:{name: client}}`. According to documentation, request body should be `{name:client}`.

#### Snippet:

```
var payload = JSON.stringify({'name' : ss.getSheetName()});//Assumin ss is sheet
```

#### References:

- [Clockify#Add client](https://clockify.me/developers-api#tag-Client)
- [UrlFetchApp#fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)

Comment: Thank you. Elementary Mistakes 'r Us [me].